# Is there a way to add Flutter to an extension Target on iOS xCode?

Tags: ios, flutter, include, flutter-engine, xcode-target

Assuming I have a basic flutter app and I add a target in xcode for the ios app. Would there be any way to link it to the main Flutter folder so I can do an "import Flutter" in the extension the same way it's done in the AppDelegate then start a FlutterEngine, MethodChannel etc locally in the extension ?

I partially succeded adding a module compiled as an "ios-framework" (otherwise with cocoapods there's a dependency conflict error) to the extension xcode target, yet this means including a redundant Flutter dependency and although it runs, I'm not sure at this point this is very stable... For this reason I'm wondering if there's a way to make an import of the main Flutter directly ?

Thanks